# Always have std::bad_cast to dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
struct Attribute
{
    std::string key{};
    std::string value{};
};

struct Tag
{
    Tag* parent{};
    std::vector<Tag> children{};
    virtual void Dummy() {};
};

struct TagName : public Tag
{
    std::string name{};
    std::vector<Attribute> attributes{};
    void Dummy() override {};
};

struct TagValue : public Tag
{
    std::string value;
    void Dummy() override {};
};

int main()
{
    Tag tag{};
    
    TagName tn{};
    tn.name = "html";
    tn.attributes.push_back({"color", "black"});
    tag.children.push_back(tn);    // add a TagName

    TagValue tv{};
    tv.value = "lorepsum";
    tag.children.push_back(tv);    // add a TagValue

    std::cout << tag.children.size() << std::endl;                // display 2 elements

    TagName& name = dynamic_cast<TagName&>(tag.children.at(0));   // I always have bad_cast exception !?
    TagValue& val = dynamic_cast<TagValue&>(tag.children.at(1));  // I always have bad_cast exception !?

    return 0;
}
```

Why I always have `bad_cast` exception, even my `tag.children.at(0)` its a `TagName` type?

P.S. The code has not include `try/catch` handler, its not the purpose of the post.

Comment: Please see ["What is object slicing?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: You are storing `Tag` elements in your `vector` by value. Object of derived types are sliced. You need to store some kind of pointers to achieve polymorphism.

Comment: And see also [Abstract classes in std containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125669/abstract-classes-in-std-containers)

Comment: If you have an `Tag` **like you do** (q.v. `std::vector<Tag> children{};` which is a vector of `Tag` objects) and `dynamic_cast` it to a `TagName`, the cast will throw a `bad_cast`.

Comment: If you have polymorphism/virtual functions and you still need a dynamic cast then most likely you need to look at your design again.

Comment: @wohlstad I have tried with pointers, the same issue, of course, no exception, but the issue remains

Comment: @Flaviu_ the accepted answer in the post from Homer512's comment ([abstract classes in std containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125669/abstract-classes-in-std-containers)) shows how to do it with smart pointers.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I need polymorphism to use dynamic_cast only. As you see, its a simple dummy method.

Comment: In C++, polymorphism **requires** using pointers or references.  `std::vector<Tag>` should be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tag>>`.

Comment: @Eljay I know that, but I choose to use reference ... it is mandatory to use pointers ?

Comment: I am still not convinced. What I think you need is to NOT use polymorphism in this case since you are not using Dummy at all. This seems to be more of a case for `std::vector<std::variant<TagName,TagValue>>` but could well be your example just shows too little so I am not sure.

Comment: About Eljay's commment, to be able to use (dynamic) polymorphism you need to create an instance dynamically ("new" them). However since naked new/delete is not recommende you should use `std::unique_ptr<Base> instance = std::make_unique<Derived>()`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I guess the code is self explanatory, its not too complicated. I need to store in Tag.children vector two types of Tag object.

Comment: Yes you need to store two types of objects, so either you need to store a pointer to the (dynamic polymorphic) baseclass OR you need to store using a std::variant.  Also your code does not show the "Attribute" class nor the "Tag" class.  What I am trying to say is that your code does not show any need for (dynamic) polymorphism. You do not call Dummy anywhere so it can be removed. Then you are left with two classes that do not need to be derived from Tag at all. So that means you just have an inhomogenous collection of classes (TagName & TagValue).. so std::vector<std::variant<...>>

Comment: @PepijnKramer As you see, both TagName and TagValue has     `Tag* parent{};
    std::vector<Tag> children{};`

So, thats why I derived both from Tag, which contain `parent` and `children` objects ...

Comment: @PepijnKramer, P.S. `children` could be removed from `TagValue`, but definitely should contain `parent`.

Comment: I am starting to understand (or at least I hope I am ;) ). Your `Tag` class should have a virtual methods `Tag* GetParent()` and `const std::vector<Tag*>& GetChildren()` and then you can call those methods on your derived classes without having to use dynamic cast to the derived classes. That's kind of what I ment if you need dynamic_cast you miss someting in your design. The use of "raw pointers" is okay as long as they are non-owning.  (C++ core guidelines [R.3](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning))

Comment: *I know that, but I choose to use reference ...*  `std::vector<Tag>` is **not** a vector of `Tag` references.  It is a vector of `Tag` objects, and *only* Tag objects — *not* anything derived from a `Tag` as a base class.