# C++ "cannot instantiate abstract class" for just iterating through them?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

```
for (AbstractThingy abstractThingy : ABSTRACT_THINGIES) {
    abstractThingy.doStuff();
}
```

Compiler is saying that abstractThingy is instantiating AbstractThingy, but I didn't instantiate I'm just looping

I then tried `AbstractThingy& abstractThingy`, but it gave the same error elsewhere.

Comment: what is `ABSTRACT_THINGIES` ? If it is a container holding instances of an abstract class you would get erros already before

Answer (score 1):

I found out in C++ we can't have vectors of abstract classes. It needs to be a vector of pointers to it. As a workaround I've simply converted the abstract class into a fake abstract class which throws an exception if I try to directly use the method that's supposed to be overridden by a subclass.

Edit: As noted by commenters the workaround wouldn't work, so I converted it to a vector of pointers. After learning about `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers it was not as much of a hassle as I thought. Only gotcha moment was `for (std::unique_ptr<AbstractThingy>& abstractThingy : ABSTRACT_THINGIES)`, you need the ampersand there to prevent it from making copies which would throw another compile error. Also, when instantiating the object via `std::make_unique` it should be `std::make_unique<ChildClassOfAbstractThingy>` rather than `std::make_unique<AbstractThingy>`

Comment: your workaround is broken. A `std::vector<FakeAbstractClass>` can only hold instances of `FakeAbstractClass>` not instances of derived types. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: That would surprise me because it compiled. Is the behavior going to be unexpected and if so in what way?

Comment: Oh poop, I guess when running it it would probably default to the base class's implementation of doStuff()

Comment: code that compiles but is still wrong should not surprise you. Try `int main() { int x = 1/0; }`. The explanation is in the link

Comment: See a question with answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2160920/509868) for more inspiration. Note: some outdated 10-years-old info there, but also valuable up-to-date info.